# Compiling and saving bootstrap less

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to compile the bootstrap less file using less js and trying to save the compiled css file to my server root folder.

I am little bit confused about which bootstrap less files to be included out of 40 less files.
Currently I am including following files to get the bootstrap css:

1. bootstrap.less
2. variables.less

For changing the variables values and compiling, I am doing following:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="bg-primary"style="width:100%;height:100px"></div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="generatecss();"> compile </a>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
function generatecss() {
    less.modifyVars({
        '@brand-primary': '#5cb85c'
    });
}
```

After executing above js function the less is compiled properly changing the brand-primary color. But my problem is that how should I save this newly compiled file to my server root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS is not typically compiled from the browser, but rather from the command-line with `lessc`. After it's installed (likely using NPM), you should be able to compile Bootstrap with something like

```
% lessc bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less my-bootstrap.css
```

Then you only need to distribute the resulting `my-bootstrap.css`—no need to serve the LESS sources.

If you want to modify that variable as you did with the JavaScript code, you can either edit Bootstrap's `variables.less` or pass another command-line option:

```
% lessc --modify-var='brand-primary=#5cb85c' bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less my-bootstrap.css
```

`lessc` can take other options as well—try `lessc --help` to view them.

Comment: If I compile less to server side, how can I pass the new variables values depending on user color selection from front end form (say any color picker) to above command line from within my app as I was doing in client side through java script.

Comment: @Saurabh: Oh, I didn't realize the variable was dynamic! In that case, on the page where the user manipulates the color, you might use the technique you were using previously. When it comes time to save that, you send the color to the server. From there, you've got options: you can either have the server serve up a bit of JavaScript with `less.modifyVars` on every page, interpolating the color the user selected; or you can compile it server-side and serve the CSS to the user. Either way, you'll have to get the server involved to a degree, and how depends on the specifics of your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think another reason I should avoid client side compilation is that my dynamic css will not be cached by the browser. Any ways for server side compilation I've to look for node js support in my production server.